# What would be the best way to hollow out the space for nostrils while modelling a head?

Tags: modeling, topology

[image]

I finally got the skull where it should be more or less. Is it possible to add in some nostrils? What would be the best way to hollow out the space? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One way would be to just inset some faces and then extrude them towards inside.

[image]

You will probably want to edit the topology of your model using another modelling tools later to add more detail to the forms. That's why I would recommend watching some video tutorials about modelling.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I haven't checked out any tutorials yet what are those. I'm not sure how I really learned this. Sometimes I just want a visual as you provide.

Comment: Well, if that works for you, then it's great. It's just that I think it might be easier to get yourself familiar with these things watching videos, because usually a lot of functions are explained together and they demonstrate ways to use them. If you look for Blender modeling tutorials on YouTube I am sure you will find a lot to chose from. People will try to answer all the questions here, that's fine if that works for you, I just think it might be faster with videos. I don't know, I guess whatever works... It seems you are on the right track.

Comment: Thanks Martin. How do I search for them are they on YT? This stuff comes easy at for me at funfundachtzig, I thought tutorials just for millenials. :-) Thanks very much for informing me.